# Update Activity's UI when it is not visible [Another activity is in foreground]

Tags: android-activity, android

Is it ok to update an Activity when it is not in the foreground. I am not asking if it can be done from a background thread.

Consider this:

I have two activities Activity-A and Activity-B.

I start an AsyncTask from Activity-A and then go to Activity-B. Now after sometime, the AsyncTask finishes and in the onPostExecute() method, I try to update the images that are in Activity-A. All this is happening when Activity-B is in the foreground.

Is the above scenario reasonable or do I have to wait till Activity-A is in the foreground to update its UI?

If I can safely update the UI in the above scenario, what should I do when Activity-A is killed or finished and the AsyncTask still completes and tries to update the UI? [Assuming I have to do a check for isFinishing before updating the UI]

The above is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. I actually have a Custom ImageView that loads images from the server and updates itself when the request is done. So I am wondering what scenarios I have to worry about if the view is updating itself when the activity is not in foreground or has finished/destroyed.

EDIT:
Here is a sample that is working.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_activity_2).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_activity_2:
            new BackGroundTask().execute();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class));
            break;
        }
    }

    private class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
    }
}
```

The Layout is just a LinearLayout with button and image.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. You can't update a UI that's not visible :) Activity A is onPause (or Stopped if needed).

You have to implement a reasonable Activity LIfeCycle so ActivityA can update its UI during onResume(); The AsyncTask should only touch the data that the UI needs to draw itself.

Your "Custom IMage View" has to be able to load the image from a place outside the Activity.

If your CustomImageView is (or can pass as a regular ImageView), you can use something like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to offload the Bitmap handling the correct way.

Comment: I created a sample app that is updating the ui of activity even after it is not in the foreground and it did update the UI as I needed. I am not saying that this is the right way but would like to know why it worked and when it would not work. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, maybe this is a wording issue. The UI cannot be updated (of an activity that is not visible) because such activity will either be paused or stopped. Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to guess what's going on. All I am saying is that you can't touch the layout of an activity that is not started. A stopped activity will have to recreate its view during its lifecycle.